# SCP transferred file does not appear on local machine

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh, sftp, scp

I'm trying to transfer files from a remote Ubuntu 16.04 server. To transfer the file, I execute this command:

```
sudo scp -P 443 asgeir@my_ip:/home/asgeir/nodejs/first_test_app/server.js \Users\Asgeir\Documents\SFTP
```

The response in the command line is:

```
server.js                                     100% 9005     8.8KB/s   00:00
```

It looks a lot like the file has been transferred, but it's nowhere to be found on my local machine. Not in the specified folder, and a search for the file doesn't return anything. Any ideas on what's going on here? (Breakfest)

Comment: If (as shown) you used backslashes instead of forward slashes, check for a file called `UsersAsgeirDocumentsSFTP` in the current directory

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you first change directory to your desired destination directory.
It looks like you are using windows, so do this:

`cd \Users\Asgeir\Documents\SFTP`

Then execute your sftp command, but instead of typing out the whole path of the destination directory, us a dot (period) instead. That tells the command to use the current directory (the one we just changed to in the last step).

`sudo scp -P 443 asgeir@my_ip:/home/asgeir/nodejs/first_test_app/server.js  .`

Now your file should be where you intend. I do this trick often when I find myself on a windows machine, especially because the windows convention of having back-slash directory delimiters and white-spaced file names to be awkward.

Happy Computing!